# Device authentication using self signed certificate

Tags: authentication, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am looking for device authentication where

1. I want to make sure that all calls to my web service\Website (hosted on Google App Engine) Is coming from an authorized device only, using a device certificate.
2. Each device will have a unique certificate that cannot be transferred to other devices.
3. A device certificate can be revoked anytime.

To achieve the above, I am planning to have another Service which would issue certificate to devices which is approved to use my service. I will issue the certificate via email to the user where he will install it manually. My users will use browser to access my service.

But I am not sure how would I achieve points 2 and 3.
Can you please guide as to how to achieve this using a self signed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I want to make sure that all calls to my web service\Website (hosted on Google App Engine) Is coming from an authorized device only, using a device certificate.

You can use a SSL channel with client authentication or adding a digital signature to your messages

> 2. Each device will have a unique certificate that cannot be transferred to other devices.

it is not possible to ensure this using software certificates. If you distribute them by email, the user could install them in several devices.

You could use a hardware token (nfc/bluetooth) or preinstall the certificate in the Android/iOS KeyChain so it would not be extractable. but this complicates the distribution very much.

> 3. A device certificate can be revoked anytime.

Check revocation at server side before accepting a request from a client. There are standard protocols to do this ( OCSP, CRL), or use a custom mechanism since you issue them yourself

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way I can get the device information in the http requests from client browser? Or store device information in the certificate?

Comment: If you are thinking of a unique device ID, it is not accessible from a browser because of security restrictions. From the server you can get the client IP. From a web application you can get the user agent characteristics: e.g "chrome 65", but i think this information would not be useful to your use case. Even if you could include this information in the certificate, it would not be accessible by the browser either. You can only verify it on the server and as long as the web application sends it in another additional request. After the SSL handshake

Comment: Do you have any additional identification mechanism, such as username / password? Alternatively you could issue a key pair after a successful login to "register" a device. The private key is stored in the browser and  and the public key is sent to server and attached to user account. Any additional request is signed with the private key. You can force that there is only one device registered at a time

Comment: My website does have a login and password but I would want the user to login only from approved device. I came cross [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28248/Securing-WCF-Services-with-Certificates) article which speaks how we can use Microsoft Certificate Services  to issue certificate. I was thinking of doing it on similar lines.
But this does not stop user from transferring the certificate.

Comment: the link is from 2008 using internet explorer in a windows. It will not adapt to mobile browsers. To use SSL with client certificates  you would need 1) generate and send them to clients 2) build a native app to generate keys, request cert and install it. In the second case you can install the cert in the device as "non extractable", but it is a complex solution.The alternative without using ssl client authentication is that of the comment above.

Comment: >> the link is from 2008 using internet explorer in a windows. It will not adapt to >>mobile browsers.
How about if I user create a service to issue certificate. This service internally users CertCli And CertEnrol API to issues\revoke\approve certificates in Microsoft Certificate Service?

Comment: I do not know the API details but I suppose you can do it